# Rails: How to validate format only if value is present?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I would like to validate the format of a form value, allowing an empty value or requiring a specific format.

To validate a value against a format, this works fine:

```
validates :application_bundle_identifier, :format => {
  :with => /^[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+$/,
  :message => "A bundle identifier should contain only alphanumeric (A-Z,a-z,0-9), hyphen (-), and period (.) characters."
}
```

Now, I would like to allow users to not enter the value at all. In this case, I could tweak the regexp to `^[a-zA-Z0-9.-]*$`, but this does not seem a very good Rails-way. Depending of the format, it might be not possible, or at least less clear.

What is the best practice in this case?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You can use the option `allow_blank: true` to skip the validation when the attribute is blank/empty/nil.

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#allow-blank

Answer (score -3):

Add `unless nil? || blank?`, which should skip the validation if it's blank (empty) or nil, I believe.

See the last code example on [this page](http://railscasts.com/episodes/211-validations-in-rails-3).

Comment: The custom validator at the bottom of the page in `lib/email_format_validator.rb`

Comment: It must have changed since you first referred to it.