# Rails Validate Field is True, If Present

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've found plenty of posts around how to validate a field is present, if another condition is true, such as these:

[Rails: How to validate format only if value is present?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763311/rails-how-to-validate-format-only-if-value-is-present)

[Rails - Validation :if one condition is true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42495133/rails-validation-if-one-condition-is-true)

However, how do I do it the opposite way around?

My User has an attribute called `terms_of_service`.

How do I best write a validation that checks that the `terms_of_service == true`, if present?

Comment: What is the datatype of `terms_of_service`? `boolean`?

Comment: Yes, it's a boolean.

Comment: To check it its `true` or to validate that it should be `true`?

Comment: I want to check that the value is true (they agreed to the terms) when the form is submitted.

Comment: And to add error if its not true, right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for the [acceptance validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#acceptance).

You can either use it like this:

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  validates :terms_of_service, acceptance: true
end
```

or with further options, like this:

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  validates :terms_of_service, acceptance: { message: 'must be abided' }
end
```

**[edit]**

You can set the options you expect the field to be as well, as a single item or an array. So if you store the field inside a hidden attribute, you can check that it is still "accepted" however you describe accepted:

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  validates :terms_of_service, acceptance: { accept: ['yes', 'TRUE'] }
end
```

Comment: I think this would normally work, but this field will be hidden (not a checkbox).

Comment: Updated my answer to include the way you can set the expectation of the field. That way, if it is stored in a hidden attribute, you can choose the answer you want to be "accepted".

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of any default validation methods that could serve your purpose, but you can do with a *custom validation*. Also, a *boolean can be either truthy or falsy*, so you just need to check if its *true or not*. something like this should work.

```
validate :terms_of_service_value

def terms_of_service_value
  if terms_of_service != true
    errors.add(:terms_of_service, "Should be selected/True")
  end
end
```

Comment: "a boolean can be either truthy or falsy" No, booleans are either true or false. Eg 1 is truthy but booleans cannot evaluate to 1.